# Emotion detection in text using Python

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am looking for libraries in Python that can detect common emotions e.g. happy, sad, angry in text besides just knowing whether a sentence/text is positive or negative. There seems to be a number of emotion detection packages in R but not sure if Python has any useful ones.

Comment: Did you search for e.g: emotion detection text python

Comment: Yes I did a search and found Text2emotion python package. I'm wondering if it is the only available package and are there more packages that could be explored.